# Unable to start Android Studio 3.0 on Windows 10

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0, android-studio-2.3

I'm unable to run **Android Studio 3.0 on Windows 10** after installation was successfully completed.

After opening Studio it got stuck on

[image: Stuck on Splash Screen]

Then I added **JDK_HOME in Environment Variables** and restarted Studio. It still dint work.

Then I added **"disable.android.first.run=true"** to **idea.properties** file in bin folder of Android Studio. It opened up the project panel, but when I start a new project it shows an error that SDK is missing

[image: SDK Missing Error]

Then I click on configure and open SDK Manager

**The SDK Manager is stuck on "looking for updates" and the edit button besides the SDK path doesn't work**

[image: SDK Manager Error]

Then I clicked on **configure->project details->project structure** and added the JDK path and SDK path. However post that, whenever I click on new project it does nothing.

I changed my Android Studio **folder permissions** to 777 and still did not work.

I also tried switching off my **Firewall** still in vain.

I have tried installing **Android Studio 3.0 and 2.3.3** but couldn't get any to work.

I have been stuck on this since 2 days and followed all instructions and posts on stack and other sources. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Check your firewall is not blocking Android Studio.

Comment: I had already switched off firewall and tried. Dint work.

Comment: is android sdk downloaded ?

Comment: Yes.. in <user>/AppData/local/Android/sdk

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I changed my region settings to US from Hindi, India and it worked like a charm. A stupid issue to waste days on.